# MVC with DAO/VO - Which DAO should the Controller talk to?

Tags: java, php, design-patterns

**Background:**

I have a design pattern problem that I was hoping someone may be able to solve. I program in PHP but I believe DAO/VO is popular in Java.

I have been using MVC for many years now. I designed a shopping that was MVC but used procedural programming. Thus recently I decided to develop the cart again, using OO.

**Problem:**

The problem I was faced with was that my Product class did not make sense to have a RetrieveAll() method.
E.g. If I had 10 products listed, from which instance would I call the RetrieveAll() method? I would have 10 choices.

**Solution:**

Thus, I found the DAO/VO pattern.
Unless I have not researched this pattern enough - I believe that each DB table must have a Model + DAO. No model or DAO should know about another set of models or DAO's. Thus being encapsulated.
The pattern makes perfect sense, pulling the database layer away from the Model.

However. In the shopping cart, my products are assigned categories. 
A category could be electronics, clothing, etc.

There are 3 tables:
- Category (pid, name)
- Category Item (iid, name)
- Category Link (pid, iid)

From an MVC approach, it doesn't make sense of which DAO the controller should be talking to?

Should it be:

- The controller talks to all 3 DAO's and then return the appropriate data structure to the View?
- Or should the DAO's talk to one-another (somehow) and return a single structure back to the Controller?

[Please see here for example (image)](http://imagepaste.nullnetwork.net/viewimage.php?id=3349)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean by VO. Is it value object?

I'm a huge fan of the [DDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) (domain driven design) approach (though I don't consider my self as guru in it). In DDD you have so called ***Services***. ***Service*** Is an action that operates on your domain and returns data. Service encapsulates the manipulation with you Domain data.

Instead of having the controller to do all the domain logic like what items to retrieve, what DAO's to use and etc (why controller should care about the Domain anyway?), it should be encapsulated inside the Domain it self, in DDD case inside a Service.

So for example you want to retrieve all the Category items of the category "electronics".
You could write a controller that looks like this (forgive me if the code have invalid syntax, its for the sake of example):

```
public function showItemsByCategoryAction($categoryName) {
  $categoryId = $categoryDAO->findByName($categoryName);
  if(is_null($categoryId)) {
    //@TODO error
  }

  $itemIds = $categoryLinkDAO->getItemsByCategoryId($categoryId);
  if(empty($itemIds)) {
    //@TODO show error to the user
  }

  $items = $categoryItemDAO->findManyItems($itemIds);

  //@TODO parse, assign to view etc
}
```

This introduces at least two problems:

1. The controller is [FSUC](http://survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/the.model#zfbook.the.model.the.fat.stupid.ugly.controller) (Fat stupid ugly controller)
2. The code is not reusable. If you would like to add another presentation layer (like API for developers, mobile version of the website or etc), you would have to copy-paste the same code (expect the part of the view rendering), and eventually you will come to something that will encapsulate this code, and this is what Services are for.

With the Services layer the same controller could look like

```
public function showItemsByCategoryAction($categoryName) {
  $service = new Item_CategoryName_Finder_Service();
  $items = $service->find($categoryName);

  if(empty($items)){
    //@TODO show empty page result, redirect or whatever
  }

  $this->getView()->bind('items', $items);
}
```

The controller is now clean, small, and all the Domain logic is encapsulated inside a service that can be reused anywhere in the code.

Now some people believe that the controller should know nothing about DAOs and communicate with the Domain only by using Services, other says that its ok to make calls to DAOs from the controller, there are no strict rules, decide what suits better for you.

I hope this helps you!
Good luck :)

Comment: The domain services I think encompases domain actions which don't fit naturally within a domain object. I don't think the domain services should return data at all, they might but this is not their purpose. This is the repository's responsability to deal with db access

Comment: @MikeSW Yes you probably right. But the question wasn't really about DDD, I just brought a design pattern (service) from DDD into the context of the question. If you want to go proper DDD then repository should not know anything about the database and should use DAO's to access the storage. I also heard somewhere that its better not to expose the repository, DOA and etc to the controller but instead expose only the Service layer, so controller uses different services to create/edit/manipulate/find the data within the Domain, and the services in turn uses repositories, factories and etc.

Comment: I kinda disagree here a bit. Only the repository should know about the db in any form. About the services, I think those are Application Services but in this case, they would be just a suplementary layer, I mean I don't think they add any value here, so the controller performs also the role of an application service.

Comment: I'm not arguing about the repository its not the topic ATM. But what if you want to say, add another access to your website, via API or web browser? You can't reuse the same controller (cause it also have the presentation logic which is different from different types of accesses) so I think eventually you will pull those calls to repositories into some other level, call it whatever you want I just call it Service.

Comment: How come a controller has presentation logic?! You're right that combining the application services functionality with the controller makes it a bit harder to change things but, at this moment (if the reuirements don't imply several types of other user interfaces) you just have classes which just increase the amount of code without any value. And truth be told I can reuse without any problem a controller in the case of a WebApi as the controller is decoupled from the input and output data format (i'm using asp.net mvc so this could be only a frameowrk detail)

Comment: Sorry I meant that the controller usually uses a **specific** presentation layer. i.e. ShowUsers controller in the webapp uses something like HTML presentation, while ShowUsers controller inside an API application might use JSON or XML presentation. But lets not discuss it there (fell free to move it into chat) since its not related to the topic. My point was that you **usually** can't reuse the same controller in different applications without modifying it, and if the controller have Domain logic (or acts as application service as you defined it) you will have to copy-paste the same code.

Comment: That's true, but when the controller is only 2 lines of code then the copy/paste isn't much of an issue.

Comment: Thank-you for this explanation skwee. I understand perfectly where you are coming from about the Service layer. 
It makes perfect sense if I wanted to make an API or pull existing controller functionality. I also agree the controller logic should be kept to a minimum.
MikeSW is right in that a service layer would be a waste if only a few lines of code would be used in the controller but I do believe this app will become quite large and multiple developers using it. Using a service layer would make it easier for the not-so technical developers to make use of it.

Comment: Yes and I was referring to Value Objects earlier (VO). The DAO creates and fills them up as needed. It can also handle CRUD operations when a VO is passed back into it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in DDD either , but this is my opinion. This is the situation where the repository patern is applied. Basically, the Domain doesn't know nor care about DAO or anything else rpesistence related. At most knows about the repository inteface (which should be implemented at the infrastructure level).

The controller knows about the domain and the repository. The repository encapsulates everything db related, the application knows only about the repository itself (in fact the interface as the actual implementation should be injected). Then within the repository you have DAOs however you see fit. The repository receives and sends back only application/domain objects, nothing related to db acess implementation.

In a nutshell, anything db related is part and it's an implementation detail of the repository.

Comment: You just create another level (repository) over the DAO, but the question still remains. What should I use? One specific repository that calls other repositories? Or call each repository sequentially (see the example with DAOs in my answer)? Finding all items by named category is an action that no Entity and no repository can provide. For the sake of encapsulation and re-usability it should be encapsulated into something like Service. And not necessarily Service as it defined in DDD context, you can as well call it Action or Command, just some layer that encapsulates common operations.

Comment: The repository has avrey clear purpose: to separate the persistence details from the rest of the application. DAO are implementation details. The repository interface is deisgned according to the application usage, you can say somehow that the repository is itself a kind of service used by the app. Finding all items by named category is exactly a method of the repository which will use the necessary DAOs to get those results. Then the repository 'transforms' the persistence objects into application objects (usually via automapping)

Comment: I agree with the roles of the repository as you described it. But lets clarify: Can repository call another repository? What repository should implement the method `FindItemsByCategoryName`, the `CategoryRepository` or `ItemsRepository`?

Comment: If you want a specific answer, the QueryItemsRepository . Once again, the repository is designed for application usage and not to wrap around DAOs. I know many developers use the repository per entity concept or something like that, but I find it artificial and pretty much useless.

Comment: Thanks for the answer MikeSW. I believe what you are saying is to create another layer just above the DAO.
However my DAO's only hold the DB queries. Their only role is to access the database and fill the VO (Value Object) with the relevant data or perform CRUD via my DB layer. It then returns the VO/s to the controller. One thing I should have mentioned is I have 'packaged' the files into modules that I could port to other bespoke systems. E.g. use my Category module in another e-cart. Thus I do not wish to have any layers low-down in the infrastructure talking to each other. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

**return type can be considered when deciding which dao method should go to which dao class, hence which dao should the controller talk to:**

Implement one DAO class per Data Entity is more cleaner,

CRUD operations should go in to Dao classes,
C-Create, R-Read, U-Update, D-Delete

Read operations are not like Create, Update, Delete, most of the time Read operations have different flavors when considering what they return.

for Read operations, return type can be considered when deciding which dao method should go to which dao class

following are some Business Entities and there Dao

```
Exchange -> ExchangeDao
Company -> CompanyDao
Stock -> StockDao
```